# run adb command after clicking a (google maps) link

Tags: windows

I have an interactive map (leaflet) that displays custom markers that contain links to google maps. When I click this link, an adb command should be executed which contains the google maps URL.

I have tried searching for different ways to do this (for example, monitor browser to open a new tab/window and grab the URL. If the URL belongs to google maps, create and run the adb-command), but couldn't find a solution for it.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You have several steps to this problem, and you should look at each step and solve them individually. You need to be able to trigger an ADB command from someplace else, you need a program that can display a map and initiate a command upon interaction, etc. Browsers severely limit interactions with the system, for good reason. All this aside, you've asked us to present a very broad solution, which isn't what this site is about. We solve single, specific issues. I suggest doing more work on your own, and as you come upon single, specific problems, this MIGHT be the right place to ask.